# schematool: command not found

Tags: hive, hive-metastore

I am trying to install Hive on my Ubuntu 19.10 machine .
I am using this doc https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-hive-on-ubuntu.
As mentioned in step 6, where I am trying to initiate Derby Database, I write the command in the right path : `~/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/bin`

```
schematool –initSchema –dbType derby
```

But I get this error :

> schematool: command not found.

How can I resolve this please ?

Comment: have u resolved this?

Answer (score 1):

run `./schematool –initSchema –dbType derby`
don't forget the ./

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question before.
Maybe because of the wrong configuration files, like hive-site.xml, hive-env.sh. A blank space in my configuration file caused this error.

Answer (score 0):

Default path for schematool is $HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool (/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/bin/schematool in your case). Try to add this HIVE_HOME on your .bashrc file, worked for me.

```
    # Hive
    export HIVE_HOME=/<your hive path>
    export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

using this command I resolved this issue

`hive --service schematool -dbType mysql -password hive -username hive -validate`